# GNU make compiling all .cpp files to .o and include .h files

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu

So i have folder that looks like this

```
OS
  Makefile
  /include
    head.h
  /src
    main.cpp
    head.cpp
  /objects
```

How can i use Makefile to compile all .cpp files to objects folder then compile all .o files with include .h to my actual cpp program.I currently have:

```
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
H_FILES := $(wildcard include/*.h)
OBJ :=$(wildcard objects/*.o)
LIBS := -Wall
CC := -std=c++14
```

What do I enter next to make all those .cpp files to .o and compile them with .h included.Thank you for your time

Comment: You shouldn't compile header files, these are included.

Comment: I will fix my statement.How do i include them then.

Comment: You use `#include` statements in the `.cpp` files.

Comment: As you can see .h files are in different folder than my main.cpp so it says they are not found

Comment: You might want to pick a good book or a tutorial instead of asking questions of that basic level. This will be more productive for you and people you ask.

Comment: I understand how i could compile these specific files together but if I let's say add more .cpp or .h files i want them to be auto included too

Comment: Add a `-I` option with the appropriate directory to the compiler flags .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) (previously known as "suffix rules") for that. As you use GNU make, you can write this line to compile all `.cpp` files in `src/` to `.o` files in `objects/`, assuming the `Makefile` is placed in the top directory:

```
objects/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

In GNU make syntax `$<` denotes the dependency (a .cpp file in this case), `$@` denotes the target (the object file).

The `.h` files do not need to be compiled, just set up the correct include path as part of the string the CFLAGS variable contains:

```
 CFLAGS += -I./include
```